# Which foreign key is correct ? And why?

Tags: database-design, foreign-key

I have 2 tables :

```
create table testContent
(
     ID_testContent int not null constraint PK_testContent primary key,
     name nchar(10),
     family nchar(10),
     ID_Image int not null UNIQUE   
)

create table ImageSources
(
    IDN_Image int not null constraint PK_ImageSources primary key,
    URL_IMAGE nchar(10)
)
```

Which one is correct ? And why ?

```
 ALTER TABLE Jb_MainDB.dbo.testContent
    ADD CONSTRAINT testContent_ImageSources_IDN_Image_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Image) REFERENCES ImageSources (IDN_Image)
```

or

```
 ALTER TABLE Jb_MainDB.dbo.ImageSources
    ADD CONSTRAINT ImageSources_testContent_ID_Image_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (IDN_Image) REFERENCES testContent (ID_Image)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your tables:

```
ALTER TABLE Jb_MainDB.dbo.ImageSources
    ADD CONSTRAINT ImageSources_testContent_ID_Image_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (IDN_Image) REFERENCES testContent (ID_Image)
```

is invalid since ID_Image is not `UNIQUE` in testContent. Assume that you could declare a foreign key like that and that your content looked like:

```
insert into testContent (ID_testContent, ID_Image)
values (1,1), (2,1);

insert into ImageSources (IDN_Image)
values (1);
```

Would:

```
delete from testContent where ID_testContent = 1
```

be allowed? One could easily imagine a theory where this would be allowed until the last tuple with ID_Image = 1 is deleted, but SQL is not defined like that. You can only reference a column that is declared as primary key or as a unique constraint. If the key is a composite key (contains several columns), all columns must be referenced. The correct foreign key is therefore:

```
ALTER TABLE Jb_MainDB.dbo.testContent
    ADD CONSTRAINT testContent_ImageSources_IDN_Image_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Image) REFERENCES ImageSources (IDN_Image)
```

EDIT: after a unique constraint is added in the OP it changes the scenario completely.

Both f.k. are now valid, it's more a question of what you want to express. Can testcontent exist without an imagesource, make that the `PARENT` table:

```
ALTER TABLE Jb_MainDB.dbo.ImageSources
    ADD CONSTRAINT ImageSources_testContent_ID_Image_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (IDN_Image) REFERENCES testContent (ID_Image)
```

If it is the other way around, ImageSources should be the `PARENT` table:

```
ALTER TABLE Jb_MainDB.dbo.testContent
    ADD CONSTRAINT testContent_ImageSources_IDN_Image_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Image) REFERENCES ImageSources (IDN_Image)
```

If both ImageSources and TestContent can exist independently of each other you can remove ID_Image from testContent and create a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE testContent_ImageSources
( ID_testContent int not null
      foreign key references testContent (ID_testContent)
, ID_Image int not null
      foreign key references Imagesources (ID_Image)
,    primary key (ID_testContent, ID_Image) 
);
```

Comment: thanks. I am editing the table. i'm confused about the direction of defining the FK. It will be define in parent or child?

Comment: Many instances of an FK can reference one instance of a PK.  But  many instances of a PK cannot be referenced by one instance of an FK.  Beyond that, which one is correct depends on the subject matter relationships.  You don't design these relationships.  You discover them.